# block access to certain website types

Tags: website, blocking

Need to block access to certain website types without listing each URL to block. Students at secondary school are going to porn sites. Need to be able to block all such access without having to list each possible site URL. Having the Content --> Ratings tab set to None for all categories on the ratings files listed on my computers does not prevent access.

Unchecking users may access sites with no rating, even with the security settings set to High, still allows the porn sites to come up. If that is checked, then ONLY listed sites can open and students would not be able to do any research via google, for example. I would rather not have to continue checking each computer and blocking sites as they find them.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) (it's free) as your DNS service provider and then use its filtering/monitoring services.

*"Join more than 40,000 schools and districts, including some of America's largest, that use OpenDNS today to achieve CIPA compliance and keep their kids safe online.
Start using OpenDNS! It's free.
Make navigating the Internet on your network a safe and controlled experience with OpenDNS. Easily achieve CIPA compliance required for E-Rate funding, and make access to online learning tools easier, while blocking unsafe and inappropriate Web sites — including proxies and anonymizers — altogether. There's no appliance to buy and you can manage filtering for all schools in your district from one centralized Web-based dashboard. "*

Comment: 2nd Vote for OpenDNS. Operates at the DNS level, so you don't have to worry about setting up programs or adding excessive NAT/Firewall rule to the router, which can hamper performance.

Answer (score 2):

**K9 Web Protection** is a kid's web filtering and blocking software that is extremely configurable. It has filtering, word block, site block, category block, time limits/restrictions and also blocks ads.  I've used it to help block content like you're requesting...

It works cross-browsers; one configuration covers Internet Explorer, Firefox, and others all one the same machine.

K9 Web Protection: http://www1.k9webprotection.com/

For Windows only, and works very well (free).  Installs separately - not as an addon, and all configurations are protected by a password...

**Note:** I'm not affiliated with this product in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: but you can always uninstall it not?

Answer (score 1):

You install [**Untangle**](http://www.untangle.com/) on a small low-powered computer as a network gateway or router, which gives you a lot of features as well as a [web filter](http://www.untangle.com/web-filter).

It's more effective than blocking through DNS services like OpenDNS, as you can't still access them using IP addresses.